# boehm-gc with C++11's thread library

Tags: c++, c++11, boehm-gc

As we know, using boehm-gc in multi-thread requires calling `GC_register_my_thread` with stack base from `GC_get_stack_base`. but It seems not to work well with C++11's thread library, such as `std::thread`... How can I use boehm-gc with C++11's thread library?

(I use VS2013)

edit: This is tested code. `std::thread` is good, but `std::future` doesn't work (stop on `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

#define GC_THREADS
#include <gc.h>
#include <gc_cpp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "gcmt-lib")

void foo()
{
    GC_stack_base sb;
    GC_get_stack_base(&sb);
    GC_register_my_thread(&sb);

    int *ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ptr = new (GC) int;
        *ptr = 1;
    }

    GC_unregister_my_thread();
}

int main()
{
    GC_INIT();
    GC_allow_register_threads();

    std::cout << "test for std::thread";
    std::thread thrd(foo);
    thrd.join();
    std::cout << " [sucs]\n";

    std::cout << "test for std::future";
    std::future<void> fu = std::async(std::launch::async, foo);
    fu.get();
    std::cout << " [sucs]\n";

    std::cin.get();
}
```

edit: here is a capture of stack trace (Sorry that it isn't English, but I think it doesn't matter, anyway)
[image]

and here is a debug message

```
HEAP[TestGC.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00E80000, 00C92F80 )
```

While debugging, I found The error occurs after `fu.get()`.

edit: The error doesn't occur with /MD(or /MDd)...

(I think GC might touch library's pointers (namespcae Concurrency), but it is just guess;;)

Answer (score 2):

Before you start using the collector and before you create the threads make sure that you issue both

- `GC_INIT`, and
- `GC_allow_register_threads`

Then in every thread follow it up with,

- `GC_get_stack_base/GC_register_my_thread`, and eventually
- `GC_unregister_my_thread`.

You didn't say what you are compiling with but it works for gcc 4.8 (with -std=c++11).

EDIT: The OP was able to resolve the issue by addressing the instruction above and compiling the code with the `/MD[d]` flags for the multi-threaded dynamic MSVCR100 runtime. The issue remained unresolved for the multithreaded statically compiled runtime.

Comment: That should be okay, the above still applies. Why the emphasis on C++11? Has it been working for you with C++98 (with Visual Studio) and now it doesn't?

Comment: There is no guarantee in the spec that std::async will run on a separate thread. You have to run `std::async(std::launch::async, foo);` if you want to force that.

Comment: I tested again with std::launch::async, but same error occured;

Comment: You'll probably need to add the stack trace of the _CrtIsValidHeapPointer failure. Btw just a quirky question - does it occur if you comment out the test for thread in main?

Comment: The problem still occurs though I commented out test for thread. and I wrote stack trace.

Comment: Did you by chance specify the `GC_win32_dll_threads` define? How was gcmt-lib built? 
Overall it look to me as if the collector is intercepting the creation of an internal Concurrency object (MS c++11 lib implementation details) so it gets deleted twice. But I'll have to check that on a box with an msvc compiler.

Comment: Make sure to check the return values of the `GC_` methods, for example, does `GC_register_my_thread()` returns GC_SUCCESS ?

Comment: I compiled boehm gc with /MT and /MTd, but I give up now;; /MD and /MDd works well, and I have suffered from this problem for several months! It seems that boehm-gc supports only shared-library runtime... thanks for your help so far. (Believe it or not, I found this fact while I follow your instructions)

Comment: But I'd rather check what you said.. (I don't like use shared library runtime T.T)